# A Terminology in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, terminology

The term *soluble (or solvable) group* came from the works of Galois, Abel, Lagrange, relating to solvability of equations by radicals.

One may ask then, how the terminology *nilpotent group* came? The reason given in the book *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups By Joseph Rotman*
p. 115, is the following:

> There is an analogue of the descending central series for Lie algebras, and Engel's theorem says that if the descending central series of a Lie algebra L reaches 0, then L is isomorphic to a Lie algebra whose elements are nilpotent. This is the reason such Lie algebras are called nilpotent, and th term for groups is taken from Lie algebras.

Shortly, the terminology *nilpotent group* came from *nilpotent elements in algebra* (in a reasonable way). But how the term *nilpotent element* came?

I guessed that nil=zero, potent=power; this is the way a nilpotent element is defined in ring or algebra.

Comment: You guessed right... if you want more, I don't know what that could be...

Comment: I was unable to discuss this point with anyone around me, since either their work is not in algebra, or they don't want to see *very old fashioned subject*. Thanks for convincing me it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you guessed right. The origin of the name lies in Latin:

- [*nihil*](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/nihil) n.: nothing, trifle
- [*potens*](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/31063/potens-potentis) adj.: capable, powerful

  - from [*potentia*](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/31066/potentia-potentiae) n.: force, power

Hence the adjective *nilpotent* literally means *without power*.